# maplacejs change map radius

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps

i'm use this library for google maps [maplacejs](http://maplacejs.com/), i'm using the circle map.  I want to change the circle radius depending on an HTML select form that have distances. I tried first to change to radius with code after loading the map it works! But then when i add the event of the select on change and i do the same code. It doesn't work anymore. I'll appreciate any help, thanks in advance.

```js
<script>
  $(function() {
  //Map config
  var LocsA = [
    {
      lat: 45.9,
      lon: 10.9,
      title: 'Title A1',
      html: '<h3>Content A1</h3>',
      icon: 'http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/markerA.png',
      animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP
    }
  ];

  var map = new Maplace({
    locations: LocsA,
    map_div: '#gmap-circles',
    start: 16,
    type: 'circle',
    shared: {
      zoom: 16,
      html: '%index'
    },
    circle_options: {
      radius: 10,  
    },
    circleRadiusChanged: function(index, point, marker) {
      $('#radiusInfo').text(
        ' - point #' + (index+1) + ' size: ' + parseInt(marker.getRadius()) + 'mt.'
      );
    }
  });
  map.Load();

  map.circles["0"].radius = 100; //Changing the radius work here !

  //Select event
  $('select').on('change', function() {
    var value = this.value;
    map.circles["0"].radius = value; //Changing the radius doesn't work anymore, here is my problem.
  });

});
</script>
```

```html
<div id="gmap-circles" style="width: 600px; height: 400px"></div>
    
<select id="distance">
  <option value="100">100 Km</option>
  <option value="500">500 Km</option>
  <option value="1000">1000 Km</option>
  <option value="2000">2000 Km</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`.setRadius`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/3.exp/reference#Circle) to change the radius:

```
map.circles["0"].setRadius(parseFloat(value));
```

[proof of concept fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/ycx7rjcc/1/)

**code snippet:**

```js
$(function() {
  //Map config
  var LocsA = [{
    lat: 45.9,
    lon: 10.9,
    title: 'Title A1',
    html: '<h3>Content A1</h3>',
    icon: 'http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/markerA.png',
    animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP
  }];

  var map = new Maplace({
    locations: LocsA,
    map_div: '#gmap-circles',
    start: 16,
    type: 'circle',
    shared: {
      zoom: 16,
      html: '%index'
    },
    circle_options: {
      radius: 10,
    },
    circleRadiusChanged: function(index, point, marker) {
      $('#radiusInfo').text(
        ' - point #' + (index + 1) + ' size: ' + parseInt(marker.getRadius()) + 'mt.'
      );
    }
  });
  map.Load();

  map.circles["0"].setRadius(100); //Changing the radius work here !

  //Select event
  $('select').on('change', function() {
    var value = this.value;
    map.circles["0"].setRadius(parseFloat(value)); //Changing the radius doesn't work anymore, here is my problem.
  });

});
```

```css
html,
body,
#gmap-circles {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<script src="https://maplacejs.com/dist/maplace.js"></script>
<select id="distance">
  <option value="100">100 Km</option>
  <option value="500">500 Km</option>
  <option value="1000">1000 Km</option>
  <option value="2000">2000 Km</option>
</select>
<div id="gmap-circles"></div>
```